# How can I filter these data per month?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

So I have these firestore data where I converted it into a JSON object. How can I filter these `data` per month and pass it inside the `datasets` inside the graph? Thank you. I think I might need to first convert the firstDose date into a javascript in order to filter these out?

I also have this in code sandbox:

[image: Edit focused-kepler-8bvv9]

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      doses: {
        dose2: true,
        dose1: true,
        selectedVaccine: "AstraZeneca",
        firstDose: { seconds: 1630374445, nanoseconds: 511000000 },
      },
      displayName: "Dark",
      address: ""
    },
    {
      address: "",
      doses: {
        firstDose: { seconds: 1630135912, nanoseconds: 920000000 },
        dose2: true,
        selectedVaccine: "AstraZeneca",
        dose1: true
      },
      displayName: "Raven"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Line
        data={{
          labels: [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "1st Dose",
              data: [10, 20],
              backgroundColor: ["red"],

              borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
              label: "2nd Dose",
              data: [30, 40],
              backgroundColor: ["orange"]
            }
          ]
        }}
        height={400}
        width={600}
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to filter the `data` *before* you pass it to any component for rendering? Later? And yes, this will likely involve converting the `seconds` to a DateTime object so you can do comparisons by month.

Comment: @DrewReese I plan to pass it inside the `data:[...]` in the graph. Do you have any explanation or way on how I can compare it per month?

Comment: Can you provide an object you are expecting for?

Comment: @capchuck the object to be put inside the `data:[...]` inside the Line Graph?

Comment: Which data do you want to filter? The object named `data` which isn't used, or the datasets passed to the graph?

Comment: @DrewReese ohh alright. I'll have to convert it to DateTime object and do the comparisons. Thank you

Comment: @DrewReese Something like I wanted to filter the `data` per month so that I can pass it to the datasets in the graph.

Comment: Is the idea then that you'd have 12 datasets to match the month labels and you want to filter `data` into 1 of those 12 "buckets"? Yeah, I think instead of filtering you should use an array reduce and process & filter the `data` array in a single pass.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to convert your `data` object into two arrays with 12 elements where every element is number of doses made in month?

Comment: @DrewReese since I'll be using a graph, then after using the array reduce and process & filter the `data` array, I could then use a `lenght` so it would count how many where in a month?

Comment: @capchuck something like that, since I wanted to put count how many users were with `dose1 = true` per month and then pass it on the `dataset` with the `label: "1st Dose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it work you'll need something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      doses: {
        dose2: true,
        dose1: true,
        selectedVaccine: "AstraZeneca",
        firstDose: { seconds: 1630374445, nanoseconds: 511000000 },
        secondDose: { seconds: 1632966600, nanoseconds: 0 }
      },
      displayName: "Dark",
      address: ""
    },
    {
      address: "",
      doses: {
        firstDose: { seconds: 1630135912, nanoseconds: 920000000 },
        dose2: true,
        selectedVaccine: "AstraZeneca",
        secondDose: { seconds: 1632727920, nanoseconds: 0 },
        dose1: true
      },
      displayName: "Raven"
    }
  ];

  const dosesTemplate = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  const doses1 = data.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      if (!cur.doses.dose1) return acc;
      const month = new Date(cur.doses.firstDose.seconds * 1000).getMonth();
      acc[month] = acc[month] + 1;

      return acc;
    },
    [...dosesTemplate]
  );

  const doses2 = data.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      if (!cur.doses.dose2) return acc;
      const month = new Date(cur.doses.secondDose.seconds * 1000).getMonth();
      acc[month] = acc[month] + 1;

      return acc;
    },
    [...dosesTemplate]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Line
        data={{
          labels: [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "First Dose",
              data: doses1,
              backgroundColor: ["red"],

              borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
              label: "2nd Dose",
              data: doses2,
              backgroundColor: ["orange"]
            }
          ]
        }}
        height={400}
        width={600}
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Hello",
            fontSize: 20
          },
          legend: {
            labels: {
              fontSize: 25
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It is possible to refactor to reduce code duplication :)